# if IE for css does not trigger when viewed in IE

Tags: css, html

I added the below condition in `<style></style>` but for some reason it does not trigger when viewed from IE.  Any idea to why?

```
<!--[if IE]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE<br />
<![endif]-->
```

It does not work inside a div too.  I want to out a particular style such ash `height:3px` when it is IE

code in : http://jsfiddle.net/z4bn8/

Comment: Why a style tag?  Does it work in a plain ole div? I thought style tags were just for css... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/style

Comment: It does not work inside a div too.  I want to out a particular style such ash `height:3px` when it is IE

Comment: Great.. so is there a solution?

Comment: @Jean - What version of IE have you tried it in?

Comment: version 7 I would like it to work for any version, without putting a condition of IE X

Comment: @JamesAllardice - http://jsfiddle.net/z4bn8/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible in a css-file or between style-tags. Try placing the condition around the style-section or include of your style sheet

Comment: Than just place the css in a separate style-block and wrap the condition around that (first solution I gave)

Answer (score 0):

[if IE] wont work inside style or within .css , try something like this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
/* css for IE goes here */
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Could you please add the code (preferably the whole html) to know what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Move the code from css into html and see it work..  See updated http://jsfiddle.net/z4bn8/2/

Answer (score 0):

See answer : http://jsfiddle.net/z4bn8/2/